# Any good workarounds to QUERY_TOO_COMPLICATED error for dynamic SOQL?

Tags: soql, governorlimits, dynamic-soql

When running a dynamic query with certain formula fields I get the following error:

```
System.UnexpectedException: Query is either selecting too many fields or the filter conditions are too complicated.
```

This usually happens if the end user includes certain formula fields in thequery that are expanded into particularly large SQL statements when they are evaluated in the query.

Is there any good way to see when you are close to this limit based on the field describe information and then split/truncate your query appropriately?

query format:

```
SELECT fieldlist from myCustomObject__c where WHERE Id IN :aRecordIds
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example value of a 'query too complicated'-producing query statement?

Comment: @MarkPond I've pasted in the query format. I can paste in the whole query but it is just pulling a bunch of formula fields from my custom object. 

I only the list of fields at runtime as it is determined based on the end users selection.

Comment: I feel you are hitting the Oracle limit. Formula fields generate SQL expressions based on the formula expression, which can get pretty large if the formula is complicated. Selecting more complex formula fields will increase the chances of hitting the Oracle 64k limit.

Comment: @subodhbahl There are under 50 records in aRecordIds. Is splitting up aRecorIds actually going to make a difference? Won't the character size of query be the same even if it returns 1 record?

The main issue I see is that there is no way for me to know the size the formula will be expanded to in the oracle query and my query is dynamic.

Comment: That's right. I was thinking 2 different things at the same time. The size of the query will exactly be the same regardless of what you compare it to.

Comment: I tried writing some code, but sorry it didn't work out for me. I have tweeted this question with the #askforce tag hopefully someone will help. I will keep my eyes on this since I want to know the answer myself! Sorry bud.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with subodhbahl, your hitting an Oracle limit, but it's more complicated than just SQL expressions based on formula fields.

The only known work-around is to reduce the complexity of your query.  Limit the number of fields, formula fields, large text area fields (limit size helps), reduce roll up summary fields in your query, and limit your filters if possible.

I've raised this issue with Salesforce support in the past, and I was told Salesforce doesn't have a formula for calculating when a SOQL query is too complicated.  We are flying blind.  Suggest adding a configurable setting to help throttle the number of fields you are querying.

Also note:  Once you start hitting issues like this, you may find issues with **mobile lite** as last I remember...the fields queried cannot be configured by administrators.  Again, no indicator that your about to outgrow your free licenses of mobile lite, it's based on when your queries become complex.

Hope these comments help.